# How to use two different version of jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The custom control i am working on contains jquery ui 1.9.2, but the projects it is supposed to be inserted in could contain any version. So, is there any way that I could change something in the library, or I could make an instance of my version of jquery ui and call the functions I need through that instance? Like, for example I make some instance named "JQUI19" and then lets say I call a function combobox as

```
$('#someElement').JQUI19.combobox();
```

or in any other way. I remember I saw somewhere a similar thing was done like

```
myJQ('#someElement').combobox();
```

but cant recall where I saw that.

Comment: Never use 2 jQuery UI versions. Which jQuery UI 1.9.2-specific features are your custom control using?

Comment: You will have to handle the name collision. You know there is no overriding and only the functions of the second js referred will be present.

Comment: actually, the developers who would be working with my control are not supposed to know what is present inside the control, neither I could bind them to use the same version of jquery ui as I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Jquery library, after the last line, type

```
var mySelector = $;
```

Include the other version after you include this in your page.

now, in all the scripts that you want to use with this jquery version(you can even use a different version of jquery ui and other libraries too), replace $ with mySelector. Use replaceall, but would be a couple of places, like in regex match functions, where you would want to replace mySelector back to $. This problem was bugging me for quite a long time. And it just got solved.

**Note : Be sure that you do not replace any $ inside the jQuery original script.**

Answer (score 3):

Never use two versions of UI.

If you are packaging something that will be reused by multiple clients and want to check if the client has jquery UI already available then you can use something like this:

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined'){
// Add Google UI Library To Head
(function() {
  var jqUiScript = document.createElement('script'); jqUiScript.type = 'text/javascript'; jqUiScript.async = true;
  jqUiScript.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(jqUiScript, s);
})();


}
```

Comment: i was thinking, why dont i declare the library in a variable, and then initialize it when I want to use any function from that library. After that i destroy it. Here is something I want to do like
    var a = function(){ //jquery ui library }
    ...........
    a();
    $('#myElement').combobox(); 
    destroyPlugin(a);//removing the script from DOM

now the part which I am not sure about is, how to destroy the plugin?

Comment: I just figured out a better solution.